# TopoJSON to GeoJSON rendering Mercator as a perfect Square, and Albers as perfect Circle using D3

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

## When I add my geojson features to the svg, all features seem to coalesce into some sort of modernist, abstract styled work-of-art.

### Clues

1. When I set the projection as Mercator, the result is a perfectly square work-of-art.
   [image: $250]
2. When I set the projection as Albers, the result is a perfectly circular work-of-art.
   [image: $500]
3. Mapshaper.org renders my file fine, because it must have been coded by some sort of superior being.
   [image]

### Code that I think is relevant

This is the fiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/d5Lqemsq/1/

```
d3.json("median_map_2_pct.topojson", function(error, nc) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);


  var featureCollection = topojson.feature(nc, nc.objects.median_map);

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(featureCollection.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path.projection(projection))
```

### Thanks for reading.

Comment: can u put this up on a fiddle for us to play around :)

Comment: fiddle added above the code.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Where did you get your topojson file? It is not in the "standard" format I'm used to seeing in topojson files I make from shapefiles. It looks like your topojson.features call does not reference any geometry in the topojson file. I'm surprised it's drawing anything at all. I could build you a topojson file of North Carolina counties sans the census data that will draw the map your trying to get.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for checking up.  The TopoJSON file came from Mapshaper.org's export feature.  I uploaded my GeoJSON file and simplified it to 1%, and then exported as Topo.  Don't stress yourself too much, as I am sure this has more to do with my (lack of) depth of knowledge of d3/topojson.

Comment: I made the GeoJSON file but realized that your map is not a county map. Those are much smaller subsections. What geography units are being displayed here and I'll see if I can make the file. You can download the county json file [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/admin4life/fiddlefiles/master/nc.json) and change your d3.json call to the nc.json file and the topojson.feature(nc, nc.objects.nc)

Comment: I went ahead and made a working example of the county map with all the code in the index.html -> [Here](http://bindust.com/nc/)